# Issue configuring Tesseract in Spring MVC (Maven)

Tags: java, spring, maven, tesseract

I'm facing some issues configuring Tesseract to work with Maven.

I've imported a the related jar files via mvn install but am unsure what to do with the other 2 dll files. Mainly:

1. liblept168.dll
2. libtesseract302.dll

   ```
   java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.next(ServiceRegistry.java:825)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageWriterIterator.next(ImageIO.java:842)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageWriterIterator.next(ImageIO.java:827)
    at net.sourceforge.vietocr.ImageIOHelper.getImageByteBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.ocr.OCR.getResult(OCR.java:21)
   ```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.formula</groupId>
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<name>Formula_0.1</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MYSQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- OCR -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code</groupId>
        <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jai-imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai-imageio-core-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-pre-dr-b04-2013-04-23</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.media.jai</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        dependency> <groupId>com.sun.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId> <version>3.0.9</version> </dependency
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- allows the route to be ran via 'mvn camel:run' -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss</id>
        <name>Maven JBoss Nexus</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2</id>
        <name>Maven central</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>
```

The is my folder structure:
[image]

The strange thing it is that it works when i run it as a java application but does not when i try to use it in a servlet.

Anyone one has any experience configuring this to work with maven?

**UPDATE:**

I added one line into my code which gave a more specific error.

```
ImageIO.scanForPlugins();//before String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
```

Error:

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302': The specified module could not be found.

at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:166)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:239)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:393)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:378)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at com.formula.ocr.OCR.getResult(OCR.java:24)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your JVM? Tesseract only runs on 32-bit JVM. Check this question:
[Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302': The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329573/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-unable-to-load-librar)

Comment: I had the similar problem solved. You can check it:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890117/tesseract-implementing-a-web-service-to-trigger-ocr-actions